# Compile simple Apache Portable Runtime 1.5.2 program

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, apache-portable-runtime

Following steps from [here](http://people.apache.org/~rooneg/talks/portable-c-with-apr/apr.html) and [here](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex26.html) I tried to compile a simple program using apr 1.5.2 and apr-utils 1.5.4. Here is the code of the program:

```
    #include <apr.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        apr_pool_t *pool;
        apr_file_t *out;

        apr_initialize();
        atexit(apr_terminate());

        apr_pool_create(&pool, NULL);
        apr_file_open_stdout(&out, pool);

        apr_file_printf(out, "Hello World\n");

        apr_pool_destroy(pool);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Now, when I try to compile it using the following Makefile, compiler returns errors.

Makefile:

```
    PREFIX?=/usr/local/apr
    CFLAGS=-g -Wall -I${PREFIX}/include/apr-1
    LDFLAGS=-L${PREFIX}/apr/lib -lapr-1 -pthread -laprutil-1
    CC=clang

    .PHONY: all clean
    all: hello

    clean:
            rm -f *.o
```

Compiler output:

```
 $ make
 clang -g -Wall -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1  -L/usr/local/apr/apr/lib -lapr-1 -pthread -laprutil-1  hello.c   -o hello
hello.c:5:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'apr_pool_t'
    apr_pool_t *pool;
    ^
hello.c:5:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'pool'
    apr_pool_t *pool;
                ^
hello.c:6:5: error: unknown type name 'apr_file_t'; did you mean 'apr_size_t'?
    apr_file_t *out;
    ^~~~~~~~~~
    apr_size_t
/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1/apr.h:356:26: note: 'apr_size_t' declared here
typedef  size_t          apr_size_t;
                         ^
hello.c:8:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'apr_initialize' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    apr_initialize();
    ^
hello.c:9:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'apr_terminate' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    atexit(apr_terminate());
           ^
hello.c:9:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int'
      to parameter of type 'void (*)(void)' [-Wint-conversion]
    atexit(apr_terminate());
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:519:27: note: passing argument to parameter '__func' here
extern int atexit (void (*__func) (void)) __THROW __nonnull ((1));
                          ^
hello.c:11:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'apr_pool_create' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    apr_pool_create(&pool, NULL);
    ^
hello.c:11:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'pool'
    apr_pool_create(&pool, NULL);
                     ^
hello.c:12:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'apr_file_open_stdout'
      is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    apr_file_open_stdout(&out, pool);
    ^
hello.c:12:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'pool'
    apr_file_open_stdout(&out, pool);
                               ^
hello.c:13:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'apr_file_printf' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    apr_file_printf(out, "Hello World\n");
    ^
hello.c:14:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'apr_pool_destroy' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    apr_pool_destroy(pool);
    ^
hello.c:14:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'pool'
    apr_pool_destroy(pool);
                     ^
7 warnings and 6 errors generated.
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

Note: In the example, I took Makefile from, there is also a link `-I${PREFIX}/apr/include/apr-util-1`, but installation of the apr-utils did not create this folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<apr.h>` header is for the [platform definitions](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/2.0/apr_8h.html). It defines what's available to APR (has WinAPI? has OpenSSL?) and the standard data types (`apr_byte_t`, `apr_uint32_t`.. etc.). It's generated automatically during build by `./configure`.

Wat you need to include is `apr_pools.h` and `apr_file_io.h` for memory pools and file IO respectively.

Further [`atexit(3)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit) expects a function pointer and you passed in a function. Instead it should say:

```
atexit(apr_terminate);
```

---

Errors like these are easy to debug on your own. When the compiler complains about an undeclared identifier from a library you are using, you almost certainly forgot to include the appropriate header.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I also had to add apr_general.h and remove a linker option -laprutil-1.

Comment: @Sergey Glad it helped you and welcome to SO! If an answer fits you, you can mark it as accepted by ticking the checkmark to the left.